# Problem with the Workbook Protection(AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'workbookPassword')

Tags: python, openpyxl, password-protection

I met a problem when I tried to protect the structrue of a workbook which was loaded with

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='filename.xlsm',keep_vba=True)
```

I used the code like

```
wb.security.workbookPassword='1'
```

but it returned

> ```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'workbookPassword'
> ```

Then I tried to create a workbook and used the code with

```
wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.security.workbookPassword='1'
```

again. It worked.

It seems the attribute is only containted in the workbook created by the openpyxl. Is it true?

What's the problem makes the results different? And how to protect the workbook correctly?

Thanks,
Fae